# Generating circles dynamically in Blazor using C#

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I will be pulling few numbers from the database and once pulled
I want to generate circles around the numbers and size the circles
based on the numbers. This means circle with 140 will be bigger than
circle with 120, circle with 60 will be smaller than circe with 120

I will be using Blazor and C# to develop this. How can I go about it?
I am new to Blazor. The circles should also be draggable.

[image]

Comment: Good question. How do you draw graphics with Blazor?

Comment: See my answer for the circles.  The draggability is a separate issue, and will for sure (I think) require javascript.

Answer (score 7):

Get ready to have your mind blown!  All modern browsers support inline SVG.  And Blazor is the absolute perfect platform to interact with SVG elements using variables.  You can literally make entire components using no HTML.

Note that since SVG is not pixel-based, your graphics will scale as big as a building and will still have nice clean lines.  Try a value of 1000 to see what I mean.

**Circle.razor**

```
@page "/circle"

<h3>Circle Size</h3>
<div>
    <input type="number" @bind="@radius" step="10" />
    <button @onclick="Flash">Flash!</button>
</div>
<svg height="@(radius*2)" width="@(radius*2)">
    <circle cx="@radius" cy="@radius" r="@(radius*0.8)" stroke="black" stroke-width="@(radius *0.05)" fill="@color" />
    <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central" fill="#fff" font-size="@(radius*0.6)px">@radius</text>
</svg>


@code {
    int radius {get; set;} = 100;
    string color { get; set; } = "#a0a";
    async Task Flash()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        for (int i=1; i<20; i++)
        {
            color = String.Format("#{0:X6}", random.Next(0x1000000));
            await Task.Delay(10);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

By the way most SVG properties can be animated for extra bling: color shifts, sizes, position, rotation, anything you want.

Comment: This is a great attempt. I will like the circles to appear line by line though and not selecting them from a dropdown exactly like the image shown above

Comment: I don't have access to your business logic, so the input is just a quick way to generate a value.  What you're asking now is basically how to use Blazor and C# in general, which would be better answered by a YouTube tutorial series than by an answer to your question.  However, I'll make a second post showing how to use Circle.razor as a component.

Comment: You don't need my business logic to be able to display the circles line by line. What I am asking is how do you display it line by line and not selecting what to display from a dropdown. I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: I've shown the solution in an additional post.  However, we've gone from the specific case of using SVG, which most Blazor people don't know about, to using Components with Parameters in Blazor, which is a more general issue and has already been demonstrated in many other questions in SO.  I suggest finding a Blazor tutorial series on YouTube, as it will definitely show how to do this.

Comment: Can you make the result vertical and not horizontal. That will be my last question for you. No luck with that. I tried to add a new line to the foreach in the parent page for the component but no luck. Looks great

Comment: That's not a Blazor issue.  It's a basic HTML issue.  You'll have to learn about HTML elements like `<div>`, about `style` properties, and about `CSS`, if you are ever going to have a chance to develop your site.  A default Blazor project already has `Bootstrap` set up, so I recommend finding some tutorials about Bootstrap to learn how to lay out your page.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer showing how to use Circle as a component.

**Circle.razor**

```
<svg height="@(radius*2)" width="@(radius*2)">
    <circle cx="@radius" cy="@radius" r="@(radius*0.8)" stroke="black" stroke-width="@(radius *0.05)" fill="#a0a" />
    <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central" fill="#fff" font-size="@(radius*0.3)px">@displayValue</text>
</svg>


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int radius {get; set;}

    [Parameter]
    public string displayValue { get; set; }
}
```

**ParentPage.razor**

```
@page "/"
@page "/circles"

<h3>Circles</h3>

@foreach (int value in Values)
{
    <Circle radius="value" displayValue="@("pop. " + value)" />
}

@code {
    List<int> Values = new List<int> { 100, 230, 300, 75 }; 
    // You'll have to come up with your own list of values however you want.
}
```

Comment: I believe that this is a pretty good answer to your question.  Please mark as "Answer" if you think so, too.